# Android: after resuming from onDestroy() , an onclicklistener is not responding

Tags: android, onclick, ondestroy

I don't know if these are related yet, but I have an app that won't let me click one of the buttons after resuming from onDestroy()

is this a known issue? the listeners are set onCreate()

and never set to null

Comment: Providing some code from both of those events (i.e. `onCreate` and `onDestroy`) would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) is the end of the life cycle for an activity. This means that the next time your activity is opened it is not "resumed" it is being created. This may be a bit confusing because even though the activity is being recreated onResume is still called. You might want to take a look at the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for a better description of what is actually happening as your activity moves through the different activity states.